# python sql TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, sql

using SQL trying to delete a client from a table that is input through a tkinter listbox and I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
```

this is the code i'm working with:

```
class delete_client:
def __init__(self):
    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
    self.window.title("Delete Clients")

    self.delete_client_lst = Listbox(self.window, width=50, height=15)
    self.delete_client_lst.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=3)
    self.delete_button = Button(self.window, text='Delete Client', command = self.delete)
    self.delete_button.grid(row=4,column = 2,sticky =E)

    self.surname_lbl = Label(self.window, text='Client Surname')
    self.surname_lbl.grid(row=2, column=0)

    self.surname_entry = Entry(self.window, width=10)
    self.surname_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)


def delete(self):
    given_surname = self.surname_entry.get()

    sql = "DELETE FROM Client"
    sql = "WHERE Surname = %s" (given_surname)
    c.execute(sql)

def close(self):
    self.window.destroy()
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
sql = "WHERE Surname = %s" (given_surname)
```

should be

```
sql = "WHERE Surname = %s" % given_surname
```

or

```
sql = "WHERE Surname = {}".format(given_surname)
```

Otherwise it looks like you are trying to call a function off your string object where `given_surname` is being passed as a function argument.

Comment: That will use string interpolation, so at major risk of injection attacks. Also, the first part of the query will be lost. Just use `c.execute("DELETE FROM Client WHERE Surname = ?", (given_surname,))`. This will escape malicious input and will also be faster.

Comment: Really  should not be using string operations here.

Comment: so, i used:

'c.execute("DELETE FROM Client WHERE Surname = ?", (given_surname,))' 

and i'm getting no more errors, but it only seems to be temporarily removing the data from the table. when i close and re-run the program they haven't been deleted...

Comment: Because you need `conn.commit()` to push the changes.